# How do you save values into a YAML file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

Inside my persist.yml file. I have the following key-value pair...

```
session = 0
```

How do I update the YAML file such that:

```
session = 2
```

Comment: Load it, modify the data, regenerate the yaml file? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was unable to find a good example online doing that. But yes. That is essentially what I was looking for.

Comment: This is such an easy task, yet it shows no evidence of effort. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Using ruby-1.9.3 (Approach may not work in older versions).

I'm assuming the file looks like this (adjust code accordingly):

```
---
content:
    session: 0
```

and is called /tmp/test.yml

Then the code is just:

```
require 'yaml' # Built in, no gem required
d = YAML::load_file('/tmp/test.yml') #Load
d['content']['session'] = 2 #Modify
File.open('/tmp/test.yml', 'w') {|f| f.write d.to_yaml } #Store
```

Comment: Also works fine in 1.8.7

Comment: `File.write('/tmp/test.yml', d.to_yaml)` is simpler and does the same thing.