# Keep comments as it is while updating YAML file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML file with many comments. I want to update it via a ruby file but want to keep the comments intact. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532959/how-do-you-save-values-into-a-yaml-file) is what I'm exactly doing now. How can I keep comments intact but also change content of YAML file ?

Comment: Preserving comments on top/bottom of the file should be easy, just le us know if you need that. Otherwise it's not probably worth the hassle. I think comments support is a common feature for XML libraries

Comment: You can't. YAML is a serialized representation of an object. Ruby has no means of commenting an object unless you make that comment a part of the object, at which point you'd use a string. You *could* treat the YAML file as a text file, and read/parse/emit it all as text. How to read and search a text file is well covered by multiple questions on SO and the internet.