# Load and save a YAML file without losing quotes or comments in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement to programmatically edit YAML files in Ruby, and I need to also retain the enclosing quote characters unfortunately.  Being able to retain the comments too would be a bonus.

That is to say if I have a file:

```
---
foo: 'bar'
```

or

```
---
foo: "bar"
```

My script must not write it back as:

```
---
foo: bar
```

And as mentioned, ideally I need to preserve comments too.

Without going down the path of just treating the whole file as a stream of text, is there any convenient way to solve one or both of these problems?

Comment: Couldn't you just follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532959/how-do-you-save-values-into-a-yaml-file) but with a string instead of an integer?

Comment: you'll need your own parser if one doesn't exist in ruby for ignoring the comment text. As for the file removing the quotes, that's per yaml spec, a string doesn't have to be enclosed but is usually enclosed when it will make the string less ambiguous (e.g. characters like `[`,`]`,`,`,`"` in it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing, it appears this is impossible to implement in Ruby, unless you are prepared to write your own YAML parser.  I investigated other languages including Perl and Python, and found there is a Python Library called Ruamel that can do this - or more accurately, it will be able to do this when all of its bugs are fixed!  So I have re-written my application in Python.  See also this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760452/3787051).