# How to create and set a local.yml variable using a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

On my application I need to encrypt some passwords. Those passwords are already on DB, so I'm making a migration that will handle to encrypt all the fields. My problem is that I want to use a local.yml variable as a key, with a randomly generated string as its value.

How can I do that on my migration?

Comment: Use the YAML module to parse the file or to convert a hash to yaml. But before you start you should consider just using [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) instead of reinventing the wheel. Chances are you will get it wrong.

Comment: I would like to not add another gem to my application. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532959/how-do-you-save-values-into-a-yaml-file), passing a SecureRandom.hex(16) to my variable, but the file loose its format and the variable gets some strange value like !binary |-
  NjcyM2RiNWY1ZjVkYWY3ZWNmNGI5YzNhMjJmODZjMmI=

Comment: ActiveModel::SecurePassword is a part of the rails core, but it does depend on BCrypt which you should be using anyways to encrypt passwords.